# How do I enable a shortcut on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I used to work at some place that  could select a line of code, and by pressing "ALT + SHIFT + DOWN_KEY/UP_KEY", it would copy this line below or above respectively.
Now I work at some place else and this shortcut command does not work.
How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is ALT + SHIFT + UP/DOWN and not CTRL + ALT + UP/DOWN?

If I correctly understand your request, then what you need is to open the preference and go to **General > Keys**. Look for **Copy Lines** and **Duplicate Lines**.

[image]

Comment: yes, i'm sure. Anyway, if it's not working ctrl + alt. I need to find out how to do it :(

Comment: I use linux, does it have anything to do with it? Cause at school it works perfectly(Windows).

Comment: Linux could cause the problem, if the OS assigned the shortcut to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL+ SHIFT+L to see a list of short cuts to check you remembering correctly.

Otherise you can customise/enble shortcuts using
Window --> Preferences --> General --> Keys

Answer (score 0):

As I use Linux, I found the problem.
It has a shortcut registered. What you have to do is disable it.
Go to System, ShortCut Keys, then you remove the shortcut "CTRL+ALT+UP" and "CTRL+ALT+DOWN".
Done, it works.